# Inner join no matching columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below table and need the following output -

```
doctor professor <--column names
tom    mary
harry  layla
```

[image]

Here is my query that doesn't work -

```
select tb1.name, tb2.name from 
(
select name
from tutorials.occupations
where occupation = 'doctor'
order by name
) tb1
inner join
(
select name
from tutorials.occupations
where occupation = 'professor'
order by name
) tb2
on tb1.name = tb2.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want a `join`.  You want `union all`:

```
select doctor as name, 'doctor' as occupation
from t
union all
select professor as name, 'professor' as occupation
from t;
```

Comment: 'doctor as name' --doctor is not the column name..how can this work?  i'm missing something?

Comment: Look at your question. You show doctor and professor as a column names. This query will produce the result you asked for.

Comment: @user1050619 . . . Your question explicitly say "doctor professor <--column names".  If you have a different question, then ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  doctor as name,
  'doctor' as occupation
from
  tb1
union all
select
  professor as name,
  'professor' as occupation
from
  tb1;
```